# Do I really need to change my document.ready section if I want to use RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, requirejs

Actually, I have something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
...JQUERY CODE HERE...
}
```

But i would like, to only change the way i included my script library and use Require.JS.
This is what i have done so far :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        requirejs.config({
            paths: {
                jquery: 'js-jQuery/jquery.js',
                jqueryui: 'js-jQuery/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'
            },            
            shim: {
                'jqueryui': {
                deps: ['jquery'],
                exports: '$'
                }
            }
        });

        requirejs([
            'jquery',
            'jqueryui'
        ]);
</script>
```

I always get an error on my "$(document).ready".  Do I really need to change my "Current" way of using "document.ready" to use a plugin like "domReady"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you just need to ensure jQuery has been included before you use it.

```
require(["jquery","jqueryui"],function($){
    $(document).ready(...

});
```

Comment: I tried as much as I can, but I still have an error.  For now I include jQuery.JS the old fashion way and all my other Lib are loaded by RequireJS.

Comment: There's also a require-jquery.js that you can include that you would use the same way as in my answer, though i don't think there's a 1.9 version of it yet.

Comment: Your paths should not have .js at the end. Remove them

Comment: @SimonSmith Tx guys With the combination of yours answers, it's finally working!